# how to convert data from r to json and can be readable by geojson?

Tags: json, r, geojson

I have retrieve data from JSON to R and edited the data to dissolve the boundary. The data from JSON consist of list of Daerah and the coordinates, longitude and latitude. So I already dissolved the boundary to Wilayah which each Wilayah consist of many Daerah and I have several Wilayah.

```
ditu <- readOGR('mys2.json', 'OGRGeoJSON')    
lookup <- read.csv("json/aaa")    
soa1 <- merge(ditu, lookup, by.x="Name", by.y = "Daerah", all.x = TRUE)    
slsoa1 <- gUnaryUnion(soa1, id = soa1$Wilayah)
plot(slsoa1)
```

My main problem is I want to save the data in JSON format and can be readable by GeoJSON. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

library(geojsonio)

library(rjsonio)

mapwilayah<-geojson_json(slsoa1)

all<-toJSON(mapwilayah)

write(all,"mapwilayah.json")